# Simple thread in C++ Error - 'Lib' has not been declared

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm trying to make the most basic Thread possible in my C++ application, which simply executes a function called Run() (which continuously loops in a near-infinite loop) and allows for other functions to be called as a result of the Thread.

As per this tutorial, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16479/Effective-Threads-in-C-Part-1-The-Basic-Thread-Cla

I created an object in MyClass (the class that has the Run() function) header file:

```
private:
    Lib::Thread<MyClass, int> listenerThread;
```

However I get the following error:

```
MyClass.h:23: error: ‘Lib’ has not been declared
```

Do I need to include something? What is the problem here?

Comment: Did you include the header for `Thread`? Is `Thread` actually in `namespace Lib`? In any case, you'd be **much** better off using an established, tested, documented library such as [Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/libs/thread/) than some random code that you found online.

Comment: Posting a single line is meaningless when it's taken completely out of context. Please provide the actual code so someone here can help you; what you've asked is the equivalent of calling your doctor and saying "My body hurts. What's wrong?" and expecting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like their project is in the `Lib` namespace.

For your purposes, you can probably just get rid of the `Lib::` part of the code.

Otherwise, you should be using the namespace or being within the namespace. See http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/ for more information on namespaces.

Comment: if I remove the "Lib::" part, I get two new errors: (1) ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'Thread' with no type AND (2) expected ';' before < token. Both errors are generated from that line. The rest of the code compiles.

Comment: @CodeGuy are you including the `Thread` header? e.g. #include "Thread.h"?

Comment: no I'm not. I guess I should download their Thread.h class. however I can't find a download link.